# Command to retrieve the list of characters in a given character class in the current locale

Tags: locale, character-encoding

What could be a way to retrieve a list of all the characters in a given character class (like `blank`, `alpha`, `digit`...) in the current locale.

For instance,

```
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8 that-command blank
```

ideally, on my Debian system, would display something like:

```
      09 U+0009 HORIZONTAL TAB
      20 U+0020 SPACE
e1 9a 80 U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
e1 a0 8e U+180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
e2 80 80 U+2000 EN QUAD
e2 80 81 U+2001 EM QUAD
e2 80 82 U+2002 EN SPACE
e2 80 83 U+2003 EM SPACE
e2 80 84 U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
e2 80 85 U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
e2 80 86 U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
e2 80 88 U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
e2 80 89 U+2009 THIN SPACE
e2 80 8a U+200A HAIR SPACE
e2 81 9f U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
e3 80 80 U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

And in the C locale could display something like:

```
09 U+0009 HORIZONTAL TAB
20 U+0020 SPACE
```

That is, the representation of the character in the locale in terms of arrays of bytes, (like UTF-8 in the first example, and single byte in the second), the equivalent Unicode character codepoint and a description.

### Context

(edit) Now that the vulnerability has long been patched and disclosed, I can add a bit of context.

I asked that question at the time I was investigating [CVE 2014-0475](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17137). `glibc` had a bug in that it let the user use locales like `LC_ALL=../../../../tmp/evil-locale` that are resolved relative to the standard system locale search path and thus allow to use any file as locale definition.

[I could create a rogue locale](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/202) for instance with a single byte per character charset where most characters except `s`, `h` and a few others were considered *blanks* and that would make `bash` run `sh` while parsing a typical Debian `/etc/bash.bashrc` file (and that could be used to get shell access on a `git` hosting server for instance provided `bash` is used as the login shell of the `git` server user and that the `ssh` server accepts `LC_*`/`LANG` variables and that the attacker can upload files to the server).

Now, if I ever found a `LC_CTYPE` (compiled locale definition) in `/tmp/evil`, how would I find out it was a rogue one and in which way.

So my goal is to un-compile those locale definition, and if not, at least know which character (along with their encoding) are in a given character class.

So with that in mind:

- Solutions that look at the source files for the locale (the locale definitions like the ones in `/usr/share/i18n/locale` on Debian) are of no use in my case.
- Unicode character properties are irrelevant. I only care about what the locale says. On a Debian system, even between two UTF-8 system locales, let alone rogue ones, the list of characters in a class can be different.
- Tools like `recode`, `python` or `perl` that do the byte/multi-byte to/from character conversion can't be used as they may (and in practice do) make the conversion in a different way than the locale.

Comment: For most locales it ultimately comes from the LC_CTYPE stuff in (with glibc) `/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n` ... which of course comes largely from the Unicode Character Database. Of course, it would be nice to have a command

Comment: @derobert, yes, while `locale` (at least the GNU one) retrieves many of the informations stored in many of the categories, things it doesn't are the most important ones in LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE. I wonder if there's a hidden API to retrieve that information or uncompile the locale information.

Comment: Yeah - you can get that info parsed - I just finally got around to wrapping up my edit. There are several commands you probably already have installed - at least I did, and I didn't even know about them. I hope it helps. Specifically `recode` and `uconv` can give you what you what you say you're looking for. Possibly even just `luit` and `od` I guess...

Comment: Thats very good! That means you dont need `perl` at all, i think.

Comment: I seem to be able to basically extract my charset from `LC_CTYPE` with just `od -A n -t c <LC_CTYPE | tsort` Probably you've tried it already, but I'd never heard of it before and I was reading through `info` and it reminded me of this - and it seems to work. There's also `ptx` but I think it's less relevant. Anyway, if you haven't tried it and decide to do so - fair warning - it does require a little patience. http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?tsort+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On GNU, FreeBSD or Solaris systems at least, this brute-force approach works:

```
#include <wctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned long i;
  int need_init;
  wctype_t type;
  FILE* to_perl;

  setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <type>\n", (argc?argv[0] : "???"));
    exit(1);
  }
  if (!(type = wctype(argv[1]))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid type: \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }

  need_init = wctomb(0, 0);

  to_perl = popen("perl -Mcharnames=full -ane '"
                  "printf \"%17s U+%04X %s\n\", join(\" \", @F[1..$#F]),"
                  "$F[0], charnames::viacode($F[0])'", "w");

#ifdef SUPPORT_ROGUE_LOCALES
  for(i=0; i<=0x7fffffff; i++) {
#else
  for(i=0; i<=0x10ffff; i++) {
    if (i == 0xd800) i = 0xe000; /* skip UTF-16 surrogates */
#endif
    if (iswctype(i, type)) {
      int n;
      unsigned char buf[1024];

      if (need_init) wctomb(0, 0);
      n = wctomb(buf, i);

      if (n > 0) {
        int c;
        fprintf(to_perl, "%lu", i);
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
          fprintf(to_perl, " %02X", buf[c]);
        putc('\n', to_perl);
      }
    }
  }
  pclose(to_perl);
  return 0;
}
```

While per C/POSIX, `wchar_t` is an opaque type that has no relation to Unicode and is only guaranteed to cover all the characters supported by the system's locale, in practice, in most systems that support Unicode, the values do correspond to the Unicode code points and the locale definitions are themselves based on Unicode.

Unicode is meant to be a superset of all known charsets, so looping over all the valid code points in Unicode (0 to 0xD7FF and 0xE000 to 0x10FFFF) should list at least all the characters supported by a given charset.

Here, we're using the system's locale standard API to check which ones are of a given type and to convert it to their encoded form in the locale's encoding. We use `perl` and its `charnames` module only to get the name from a given Unicode codepoint.

On locales that use stateful encodings like ISO-2022-JP, we make sure the encoded form is displayed from a default initial state.

I've not found a system that had installed locales with a stateful character encoding but at least on GNU systems, it is possible to generate some so a rogue locale could be made to (and at least GNU tools don't work properly in those locales). For instance, with a custom locale that uses ISO-2022-JP with a normal `ja_JP` locale, I get:

```
$ LOCPATH=$PWD LC_ALL=ja_JP.ISO-2022-JP ~/list-type blank
       09 U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
       20 U+0020 SPACE
   1B 24 42 21 21 U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

Compare with:

```
$ LC_ALL=ja_JP.eucjp ~/list-type blank
       09 U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
       20 U+0020 SPACE
    A1 A1 U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

In ISO-2022-JP, the `1B 24 42` sequence (`\e$B`) switches from ASCII to a state where characters are expressed as 2 (7-bit) bytes (here 21 21 for that IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE). While in EUCJP, it's the same bytes but the *state switching* is done by flipping the 8th bit (`A1 = 21 | 0x80`) which makes it more stateless.

That means that in those stateful encodings, there are several ways to write a given character (for instance by inserting several of those *state switching* sequences), and the shown sequence by that code above is just one of them (the canonical one from an initial default state).

While for a normal locale, characters can't be outside 0..0xD7FF, 0xE000..0x10FFFF, for a *rogue* locale, any character in the range supported by wchar_t may be. For instance, I could create a locale where U+DCBA or U+12345678 characters (or would be characters if they were allowed) are *blanks*. That's why you'd want to compile that code with `-D SUPPORT_ROGUE_LOCALES` to cover those, though that means it takes a lot more time to scan the whole list.

I couldn't use @mikeserv's solution as `recode` uses its own conversions, is no longer maintained and only supports Unicode characters up to 0xFFFF, and GNU `tr` at least doesn't work with multi-byte characters.

I couldn't use [@ChrisDown's](/a/128193) as `python` doesn't have interfaces to the POSIX character classes.

I tried Perl, but it's bogus for code points between 128 and 255 for multi-bytes locales other than UTF-8 and doesn't use the system's conversion libraries.

Comment: I think this is effectively the only way to do it, but it suffers from several problems, starting with the fact that you used prior knowledge to decide about the range of legal codepoints. In theory at least, if you're using a Unicode charmap, the character classes are independent of the script (according to Unicode standard, not C locales), but the Unicode "general categories" are not the same as C character classes either. BTW, glibc's i18n ctypes include two more character classes: `combining` and `combining_level3` (viz. `iswctype(i, wctype("combining"))`)

Comment: @rici, see edit (and also of the question).

Answer (score 10):

#### POSSIBLE FINAL SOLUTION

So I've taken all of the below information and come up with this:

```
for class in $(
    locale -v LC_CTYPE | 
    sed 's/combin.*//;s/;/\n/g;q'
) ; do 
    printf "\n\t%s\n\n" $class
    recode u2/test16 -q </dev/null | 
    tr -dc "[:$class:]" | 
    od -A n -t a -t o1z -w12
done
```

#### *NOTE*:

I use `od` as the final filter above for preference and because I know I won't be working with multi-byte characters, which it will not correctly handle.  `recode u2..dump` will both generate output more like that specified in the question and handle wide characters correctly.

#### OUTPUT

```
        upper

   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 110 111 112 113 114  >ABCDEFGHIJKL<
   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X
 115 116 117 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 130  >MNOPQRSTUVWX<
   Y   Z
 131 132                                          >YZ<

        lower

   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l
 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 150 151 152 153 154  >abcdefghijkl<
   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x
 155 156 157 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 170  >mnopqrstuvwx<
   y   z
 171 172                                          >yz<

        alpha

   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 110 111 112 113 114  >ABCDEFGHIJKL<
   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X
 115 116 117 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 130  >MNOPQRSTUVWX<
   Y   Z   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
 131 132 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 150 151 152  >YZabcdefghij<
   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v
 153 154 155 156 157 160 161 162 163 164 165 166  >klmnopqrstuv<
   w   x   y   z
 167 170 171 172                                  >wxyz<

        digit

   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
 060 061 062 063 064 065 066 067 070 071          >0123456789<

       xdigit                                                                                          

   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B
 060 061 062 063 064 065 066 067 070 071 101 102  >0123456789AB<
   C   D   E   F   a   b   c   d   e   f
 103 104 105 106 141 142 143 144 145 146          >CDEFabcdef<

        space

  ht  nl  vt  ff  cr  sp
 011 012 013 014 015 040                          >..... <

        print

  sp   !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +
 040 041 042 043 044 045 046 047 050 051 052 053  > !"#$%&'()*+<
   ,   -   .   /   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
 054 055 056 057 060 061 062 063 064 065 066 067  >,-./01234567<
   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?   @   A   B   C
 070 071 072 073 074 075 076 077 100 101 102 103  >89:;<=>?@ABC<
   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
 104 105 106 107 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117  >DEFGHIJKLMNO<
   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [
 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 130 131 132 133  >PQRSTUVWXYZ[<
   \   ]   ^   _   `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g
 134 135 136 137 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147  >\]^_`abcdefg<
   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s
 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 160 161 162 163  >hijklmnopqrs<
   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~
 164 165 166 167 170 171 172 173 174 175 176      >tuvwxyz{|}~<

        graph

   !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,
 041 042 043 044 045 046 047 050 051 052 053 054  >!"#$%&'()*+,<
   -   .   /   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
 055 056 057 060 061 062 063 064 065 066 067 070  >-./012345678<
   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?   @   A   B   C   D
 071 072 073 074 075 076 077 100 101 102 103 104  >9:;<=>?@ABCD<
   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P
 105 106 107 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 120  >EFGHIJKLMNOP<
   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \
 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 130 131 132 133 134  >QRSTUVWXYZ[\<
   ]   ^   _   `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
 135 136 137 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 150  >]^_`abcdefgh<
   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 160 161 162 163 164  >ijklmnopqrst<
   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~
 165 166 167 170 171 172 173 174 175 176          >uvwxyz{|}~<

        blank

  ht  sp
 011 040                                          >. <

        cntrl

 nul soh stx etx eot enq ack bel  bs  ht  nl  vt
 000 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 010 011 012 013  >............<
  ff  cr  so  si dle dc1 dc2 dc3 dc4 nak syn etb
 014 015 016 017 020 021 022 023 024 025 026 027  >............<
 can  em sub esc  fs  gs  rs  us del
 030 031 032 033 034 035 036 037 177              >.........<

        punct

   !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,
 041 042 043 044 045 046 047 050 051 052 053 054  >!"#$%&'()*+,<
   -   .   /   :   ;   <   =   >   ?   @   [   \
 055 056 057 072 073 074 075 076 077 100 133 134  >-./:;<=>?@[\<
   ]   ^   _   `   {   |   }   ~
 135 136 137 140 173 174 175 176                  >]^_`{|}~<

        alnum

   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B
 060 061 062 063 064 065 066 067 070 071 101 102  >0123456789AB<
   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
 103 104 105 106 107 110 111 112 113 114 115 116  >CDEFGHIJKLMN<
   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
 117 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 130 131 132  >OPQRSTUVWXYZ<
   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l
 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 150 151 152 153 154  >abcdefghijkl<
   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x
 155 156 157 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 170  >mnopqrstuvwx<
   y   z
```

#### PROGRAMMER'S API

As I demonstrate below, `recode` will provide you your complete character map. According to its manual, it does this according first to the current value of the `DEFAULT_CHARSET` environment variable, or, failing that, it [operates exactly as you specify:](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/recode/recode_8.html)

> When a *charset* name is omitted or left empty, the value of the `DEFAULT_CHARSET` variable in the environment is used instead. If this variable is not defined, the `recode` library uses the ***current locale's encoding.*** On *POSIX* compliant systems, this depends on the first non-empty value among the environment variables `LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, LANG` and can be determined through the command `locale charmap.`

Also worth noting about `recode` is that it [*is an api*](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/recode/recode_16.html):

> The program named `recode` is just an application of its recoding library. The recoding library is available separately for other C programs. A good way to acquire some familiarity with the recoding library is to get acquainted with the `recode` program itself.
>
> To use the recoding library once it is installed, a C program needs to have a line:

`#include <recode.h>`

For internationally-friendly string comparison The `POSIX` and `C` standards define the [`strcoll()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/strcoll.html) function:

> The `strcoll()` function shall compare the string pointed to by `s1` to
>   the string pointed to by `s2`, both interpreted as appropriate to the
>   LC_COLLATE category of the current locale.
>
> The `strcoll()` function shall not change the
>   setting of errno if successful.
>
> Since no return value is reserved to indicate an error, an application
>   wishing to check for error situations should set errno to 0, then call
>   `strcoll()`, then check errno.

Here is a [separately located](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcoll.htm) example of its usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   char str1[15];
   char str2[15];
   int ret;


   strcpy(str1, "abc");
   strcpy(str2, "ABC");

   ret = strcoll(str1, str2);

   if(ret > 0)
   {
      printf("str1 is less than str2");
   }
   else if(ret < 0) 
   {
      printf("str2 is less than str1");
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("str1 is equal to str2");
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Regarding the `POSIX` character classes, you've already noted you used the `C` API to find these. For unicode character and classes you can use `recode's` *dump-with-names* charset to get the desired output. From its [manual again](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/recode/recode_29.html):

> For example, the command `recode l2..full < input` implies a necessary
>   conversion from *Latin-2* to *UCS-2,* as *dump-with-names* is only connected
>   out from *UCS-2.* In such cases, `recode` does not display the original
>   *Latin-2* codes in the dump, only the corresponding *UCS-2* values. To
>   give a simpler example, the command

```
 echo 'Hello, world!' | recode us..dump
```

> produces the following output:

```
UCS2   Mne   Description

0048   H     latin capital letter h 
0065   e     latin small letter e
006C   l     latin small letter l 
006C   l     latin small letter l
006F   o     latin small letter o 
002C   ,     comma 
0020  SP     space 
0077   w     latin small letter w 
006F   o     latin small letter o 
0072   r     latin small letter r 
006C   l     latin small letter l 
0064   d     latin small letter d 
0021   !     exclamation mark 
000A   LF    line feed (lf)
```

> The descriptive comment is given in English and ASCII, yet if the
>   English description is not available but a French one is, then the
>   French description is given instead, using Latin-1. However, if the
>   `LANGUAGE` or `LANG` environment variable begins with the letters *fr*,
>   then listing preference goes to French when both descriptions are
>   available.

Using similar syntax to the above combined with its [included test dataset](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/recode/recode_62.html) I can get my own character map with:

```
recode -q u8/test8..dump </dev/null
```

#### OUTPUT

```
UCS2   Mne   Description

0001   SH    start of heading (soh)
0002   SX    start of text (stx)
0003   EX    end of text (etx)    
...
002B   +     plus sign
002C   ,     comma
002D   -     hyphen-minus
...
0043   C     latin capital letter c
0044   D     latin capital letter d
0045   E     latin capital letter e
...
006B   k     latin small letter k
006C   l     latin small letter l
006D   m     latin small letter m
...
007B   (!    left curly bracket
007C   !!    vertical line
007D   !)    right curly bracket
007E   '?    tilde
007F   DT    delete (del)
```

But for common characters, `recode` is apparently not necessary. This should give you named chars for everything in 128-byte charset:

```
printf %b "$(printf \\%04o $(seq 128))" | 
luit -c |
od -A n -t o1z -t a -w12
```

#### OUTPUT

```
 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 010 011 012 013 014  >............<
 soh stx etx eot enq ack bel  bs  ht  nl  vt  ff
...
 171 172 173 174 175 176 177                      >yz{|}~.<
   y   z   {   |   }   ~ del
```

Of course, only 128-bytes are represented, but that's because my locale, *utf-8* charmaps or not, uses the *ASCII* charset and nothing more. So that's all I get. If I ran it without `luit` filtering it though, `od` would would roll it back around and print the same map again up to `\0400.`

There are two major problems with the above method, though. First there is the system's collation order - for non-ASCII locales the bite values for the charsets are not simply in `seq`uence, which, as I think , is likely the core of the problem you're trying to solve.

Well, GNU `tr's man`page states that it will expand the `[:upper:]` `[:lower:]` classes in order - but that's not a lot.

I imagine some heavy-handed solution could be implemented with `sort` but that would be a rather unwieldy tool for a backend programming API.

`recode` will do this thing correctly, but you didn't seem too in love with the program the other day. Maybe today's edits will cast a more friendly light on it or maybe not.

GNU also offers the `gettext` function library, and it seems to be able to [address this problem](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Charset-conversion) at least for the `LC_MESSAGES` context:

> — Function: `char * bind_textdomain_codeset` (`const char *domainname,
>   const char *codeset`)
>
> The `bind_textdomain_codeset` function can be used
>   to specify the output character set for message catalogs for domain
>   *domainname*. The *codeset* argument must be a valid *codeset* name which
>   can be used for the *iconv_open* function, or a null pointer.
>
> If the *codeset* parameter is the null pointer, `bind_textdomain_codeset`
>   returns the currently selected *codeset* for the domain with the name
>   *domainname*. It returns NULL if no *codeset* has yet been selected.
>
> The `bind_textdomain_codeset` function can be used several times. If
>   used multiple times with the same domainname argument, the later call
>   overrides the settings made by the earlier one.
>
> The `bind_textdomain_codeset` function returns a pointer to a string
>   containing the name of the selected codeset. The string is allocated
>   internally in the function and must not be changed by the user. If the
>   system went out of core during the execution of
>   `bind_textdomain_codeset`, the return value is NULL and the global
>   variable errno is set accordingly.

You might also use native [Unicode character *categories*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), which are language independent and forego the POSIX classes altogether, or perhaps to call on the former to provide you enough information to define the latter.

> In addition to complications, Unicode also brings new possibilities.
>   One is that each Unicode character belongs to a certain *category.* You
>   can match a single character belonging to the "letter" category with
>   `\p{L}`. You can match a single character not belonging to that category
>   with `\P{L}`.
>
> Again, "character" really means "Unicode code point". `\p{L}` matches a
>   single code point in the category "letter". If your input string is `à`
>   encoded as `U+0061 U+0300`, it matches `a` without the accent. If the
>   input is `à` encoded as `U+00E0`, it matches `à` with the accent. The reason
>   is that both the code points `U+0061 (a)` and `U+00E0 (à)` are in the
>   category "letter", while `U+0300` is in the category "mark".
>
> You should now understand why `\P{M}\p{M}*+` is the equivalent of `\X`.
>   `\P{M}` matches a code point that is not a combining mark, while `\p{M}*+`
>   matches zero or more code points that are combining marks. To match a
>   letter including any diacritics, use `\p{L}\p{M}*+`. This last regex
>   will always match `à`, regardless of how it is encoded. The possessive
>   quantifier makes sure that backtracking doesn't cause `\P{M}\p{M}*+` to
>   match a non-mark without the combining marks that follow it, which `\X`
>   would never do.

The same website that provided the above information also discusses [`Tcl`'s own *POSIX*-compliant](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html) regex implementation which might be yet another way to achieve your goal.

And last among solutions I will suggest that you can interrogate the `LC_COLLATE` file itself for the complete and *in-order* system character map. This may not seem easily done, but I achieved some success with the following after compiling it with `localedef` as demonstrated below:

```
<LC_COLLATE od -j2K -a -w2048 -v  | 
tail -n2 | 
cut -d' ' -f$(seq -s',' 4 2 2048) | 
sed 's/nul\|\\0//g;s/  */ /g;:s;
    s/\([^ ]\{1,3\}\) \1/\1/;ts;
    s/\(\([^ ][^ ]*  *\)\{16\}\)/\1\n/g'

 dc1 dc2 dc3 dc4 nak syn etb can c fs c rs c sp ! "
# $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B
C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R
S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b
c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r
s t u v w x y z { | } ~ del soh stx etx
eot enq ack bel c ht c vt cr c si dle dc1 del
```

It is, admittedly, currently flawed but I hope it demonstrates the possibility at least.

#### AT FIRST BLUSH

```
strings $_/en_GB

#OUTPUT

int_select "<U0030><U0030>"
...
END LC_TELEPHONE
```

It really didn't look like much but then I started noticing `copy` commands throughout the list. The above file seems to `copy` in *"en_US"* for instance, and another real big one that it seems they all share to some degree is `iso_14651_t1_common`.

Its pretty big:

```
strings $_ | wc -c

#OUTPUT
431545
```

Here is the intro to `/usr/share/i18n/locales/POSIX`:

```
# Territory:
# Revision: 1.1
# Date: 1997-03-15
# Application: general
# Users: general
# Repertoiremap: POSIX
# Charset: ISO646:1993
# Distribution and use is free, also for
# commercial purposes.
LC_CTYPE
# The following is the POSIX Locale LC_CTYPE.
# "alpha" is by default "upper" and "lower"
# "alnum" is by definiton "alpha" and "digit"
# "print" is by default "alnum", "punct" and the <U0020> character
# "graph" is by default "alnum" and "punct"
upper   <U0041>;<U0042>;<U0043>;<U0044>;<U0045>;<U0046>;<U0047>;<U0048>;\
        <U0049>;<U004A>;<U004B>;<U004C>;<U004D>;<U004E>;<U004F>;
```

...

You can `grep` through this of course, but you might just:

```
recode -lf gb
```

Instead. You'd get something like this:

```
Dec  Oct Hex   UCS2  Mne  BS_4730

  0  000  00   0000  NU   null (nul)
  1  001  01   0001  SH   start of heading (soh)
...
```

... AND MORE

There is also `luit` terminal UTF-8 `pty` translation device I guess that acts a go-between for XTerms without UTF-8 support. It handles a lot of switches - such as logging all converted bytes to a file or `-c` as a simple `|pipe` filter.

I never realized there was so much to this - the locales and character maps and all of that. This is apparently a very *big deal* but I guess it all goes on behind the scenes. There are - at least on my system - a couple hundred `man 3` related results for locale related searches.

And also there is:

```
zcat /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/UTF-8*gz | less

    CHARMAP
<U0000>     /x00         NULL
<U0001>     /x01         START OF HEADING
<U0002>     /x02         START OF TEXT
<U0003>     /x03         END OF TEXT
<U0004>     /x04         END OF TRANSMISSION
<U0005>     /x05         ENQUIRY
...
```

That will go on for a *very* long while.

The `Xlib` functions handle this all of the time - `luit` is a part of that package.

The `Tcl_uni...` functions might prove useful as well.

just a little `<tab>` completion and `man` searches and I've learned quite a lot on this subject.

With `localedef` - you can compile the `locales` in your `I18N` directory. The output is funky, and not extraordinarily useful - not like the `charmaps` at all - but you can get the raw format just as you specify above like I did:

```
mkdir -p dir && cd $_ ; localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_GB ./ 

ls -l
total 1508
drwxr-xr-x 1 mikeserv mikeserv      30 May  6 18:35 LC_MESSAGES
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv     146 May  6 18:35 LC_ADDRESS
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 1243766 May  6 18:35 LC_COLLATE
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv  256420 May  6 18:35 LC_CTYPE
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv     376 May  6 18:35 LC_IDENTIFICATION
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv      23 May  6 18:35 LC_MEASUREMENT
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv     290 May  6 18:35 LC_MONETARY
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv      77 May  6 18:35 LC_NAME
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv      54 May  6 18:35 LC_NUMERIC
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv      34 May  6 18:35 LC_PAPER
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv      56 May  6 18:35 LC_TELEPHONE
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv    2470 May  6 18:35 LC_TIME
```

Then with `od` you can read it - bytes and strings:

```
od -An -a -t u1z -w12 LC_COLLATE | less

 etb dle enq  sp dc3 nul nul nul   T nul nul nul
  23  16   5  32  19   0   0   0  84   0   0   0  >... ....T...<
...
```

Though it is a long way off from winning a beauty contest, that is usable output. And `od` is as configurable as you want it to be as well, of course.

I guess I also forgot about these:

```
    perl -mLocale                                                                                       

 -- Perl module --
Locale::Codes                    Locale::Codes::LangFam           Locale::Codes::Script_Retired
Locale::Codes::Constants         Locale::Codes::LangFam_Codes     Locale::Country
Locale::Codes::Country           Locale::Codes::LangFam_Retired   Locale::Currency
Locale::Codes::Country_Codes     Locale::Codes::LangVar           Locale::Language
Locale::Codes::Country_Retired   Locale::Codes::LangVar_Codes     Locale::Maketext
Locale::Codes::Currency          Locale::Codes::LangVar_Retired   Locale::Maketext::Guts
Locale::Codes::Currency_Codes    Locale::Codes::Language          Locale::Maketext::GutsLoader
Locale::Codes::Currency_Retired  Locale::Codes::Language_Codes    Locale::Maketext::Simple
Locale::Codes::LangExt           Locale::Codes::Language_Retired  Locale::Script
Locale::Codes::LangExt_Codes     Locale::Codes::Script            Locale::gettext
Locale::Codes::LangExt_Retired   Locale::Codes::Script_Codes      locale
```

I probably forgot about them because I couldn't get them to work. I never use `Perl` and I don't know how to load a module properly I guess. But the `man` pages look pretty nice. In any case, something tells me you'll find calling a Perl module at least a little less difficult than did I. And, again, these were already on my computer - and I never even use Perl. There are also notably a few `I18N` that I wistfully scrolled by knowing full well I wouldn't get them to work either.

Comment: That's all very nice and useful info, but that gives information on the source files (in `i18n`) that may or may not have been used to generate the locale I'm currently using. The locale information is probably coming from `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` or `/some/dir/LC_CTYPE`, and that's the _part relevant to my locale_ that is stored in those files that I'm after.

Comment: @StephaneChezales - so just extract your `LC_STUFF` from the archive with `localedef` - it does that too. I can demo that as well, i guess. You can also view that and pretty much everything else with `strings` or `od` or any of the rest. I did, anyway. But by the way - the `charmaps` *are* the locale youre currently using - and `localedef` will report on that as well. Also thats what `recode` does too.

Comment: You're basically saying that we can do by hand what the system's libraries to do query character class information, but that's going to need thousands of lines of code to do that reliably and the result will be system specific. (parsing the environment the same way the system library does (LOCPATH, LANG, LANGUAGE, LC_CTYPE..., identify where to look for the data, extract it...). I can't see how to extract stuff from the archive with localedef though.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I don't suggest you do it by hand - I suggest you do it with a computer - using system binaries such as `od,` `recode`, `uconv`, and the rest. But it was my mistake - it's not `localedef` that extracts it, it's `recode` that will. You've gotta check out `info recode` - and besides the `recode` table command I show up there is much the same thing - and it will handle things in that same way, I think. It doesn't just pull your charset out of thin air. In any case I did have high hopes for those `perl` modules - did you try any out?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - and you, of course *can* parse it using the system libs - like I said, there are hundreds of `man 3` results for `locale` related functions on my machine.

Comment: If there's an API to retrieve the list of characters in a given character class in the current locale, then that's specifically what I'm looking for.  If you can demonstrate how to do this, I'll accept the answer. The only thing I could think of (and how I obtained the "expected output" in my question) is to use `iswblank(3)` for all possible character values.

Comment: @StephaneChezales - `man 3 charnames` looks pretty promising: `..."use charnames"` is used to gain access to the names of the Unicode characters and named character sequences...  And, it's kinda funny, but i think you can do this with `printf/scanf`. Maybe im misinterpreting, but the example on the `scanf 3` page looks pretty close to me...

Comment: @StephaneChezales It looks like `perl's` `POSIX::` module should get you what you want, though it might take a little bit of work. I dont about *all possible* i dont know how many that is, but `perllocale 3` makes some pretty definite statements about the behavior of `POSIX::isupper()` and lower and the rest of yhe POSIX char classes. It states a limitation of 256 chars - is that acceptable? I didnt know there were any more than 128 of them til yesterday, really. In any case, i imagine you could just `setlocale()` then `print` bytes 0-256 at each of those and youd have what you wanted.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I have updated this answer a great deal - specifally to include several prpgrammnig APIS that I believe could be what you need.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - finally finished. Does it work?

Comment: Well. `recode u8/test8` doesn't make sense. utf8 is a multi-byte charset where only the subset of characters in common with ASCII are single-byte, so that command will output the byte values from 0 to 127 which has no reason to be the list of characters in the current locale. Then, GNU `tr` only works with single-byte characters. `recode ucs2/test16..` would have been more useful (though it's limited to the first 65536 characters of iso-10646 so may not cover all the characters in the current charset, and uses `recode`'s own charset database which may be different from the system's).

Comment: @Stephane_Chezales Well, good point about test8/16, but recode's charset is unlikely to he diffrent than the system's. Moreover, i also demonstrated it is possible to get the system's charset from LC_COLLATE - you just have to uncollate it. Im not going to hold your hand. There is more than enough information in the answer above to solve your problem.

Comment: The charset is in LC_CTYPE (and to some extent in the gconv modules in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv and the like), LC_COLLATE is for the collating/ordering. My goal is to get data from the system's locale definition for instance to uncompile locales used in exploits to CVE-2014-0475, so recode's own charsets (which by the way do differ) would be of little use to me is those contexts.

Comment: @StephaneChezales - the charset is also in LC_COLLATE - in order. But im sorry about the hold your hand thing - thats partly due to frustration but probably mostly because im a jerk. gconv is the iconv lib - which has been rolled into recode. Have a look at this: `od -j2k -A n -t a -w4 <LC_COLLATE` - you have to see the same pattern i do. Also, look at the 2k offset of that file and probably youll see why i specify it as `od's` jump point.

Comment: @mikeserv: LC_COLLATE does not need to list all the characters in the charset (although it might), and it doesn't define character types. In fact, for wide characters, both LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE may (and frequently do) contain codes which don't exist in the locale's repertoire, in the sense that there is no external encoding of those codepoints.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Do you have a link for that vulnerability? All I can find is a placeholder and it would be easier to help if I knew what the nature of the problem was.

Comment: @rici - not *need* to and *might*? Why *might* it if it doesnt *need* to?

Comment: @rici - and besides, if it didnt list all then it would at least list the start points for the classes, yes? Seems like it would *need* to do that at least.

Comment: @mikeserv: Because it's convenient to not customize collation definitions for subsets of character sets. Why would collation order care about character class start points?

Comment: @rici As i understand it, the collation order governs the class start points - how can a class be collated at all if the collation order does not apply?

Comment: @mikeserv: Nope. Collation order is for sorting. Nothing to do with character types. (I'm not sure if we understand the same thing by "character class"; in this context, I (and OP, I believe) refer to the equivalence classes defined by `wctype` and friends.)

Comment: @mikeserv: By the way, characters not listed in LC_COLLATE go at the end of the collation sequence in order by their character code. So it's not necessary to list every character, since there is a default order.

Comment: @rici Oh. Equivalence classes are not at all what i was referring to. In all of the docs ive seen `[:char class:]` and `[=equivalence class=]` are completely separate things.

Comment: @mikeserv: I meant "equivalence class" in the formal logical sense, not in the context of regular expression slang. But anyway, I fail to see why you think that collation order needs to care about the start- and end- points of the ranges of, for example, characters for which `iswupper` is true.

Comment: @rici and Stephane, if youre after wide char equivalence classes then you might have some luck with the Unicode native regex than otherwise, but everything ive read points to little hope on that front - at least universally.

Comment: @rici Formal logic - bitwise math? I dont think that applies universally either. You cant XOR to an umlaut as far as i know.

Comment: @mikeserv: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equivalence-class

Comment: @rici - Right as in `[=n=] ` expands to n and ennya and the rest of the equivalent wide chars which i dont know how to type on my phone because they're a set of equivalent chars depending on region - but theyre not in the same char set. And if chars not in lc_collate fall in line by order of their char code then retrieving them is as simple as `seq` uencing them - which cant be very hard.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - this is also interesting, I think: `od -A n -t c -w4 <LC_CTYPE |head -n500 | sed '/^ \{1,3\}/s///;/^\(.[^ ]*\).*/s//\1/'
`