# How do I turn accented lowercase letters to uppercase? - Using the 'tr' command

Tags: shell, regular-expression, posix, tr

I'm tryed with:

```
$ echo 'Ciência' | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
CIêNCIA
```

But the 'ê' character does not change, obviously because it is accentuated.
Then I tried with POSIX classes:

```
echo "Ciência" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
CIêNCIA
```

But the 'ê' continue in lower case.

Could someone help me?

Comment: This has to do with the locale.  What distro are you using?

Comment: I'm using Parrot GNU/Linux 3.2 CyberSloop, it's based on the latest stable Debian.

Comment: Very odd.  This works on Mac OS X without any fiddling, but I can't get it to work on my CentOS 6 test box no matter what I do with the locale.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128192/135943 is relevant here.

Comment: I think it's because my system is set to English, this should affect bash or whatever ... the environment variables ... Accents give me a headache and Portuguese is full of them for my bad luck. Well, the 'gawk' that Thomas Dickey suggested worked right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with gawk:

```
echo "Ciência" | gawk '{print toupper($0);}'
```

(also perl, someone is certain to point out).  The example uses UTF-8, which is not explicitly part of [POSIX awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).  gawk's documentation mentions these issues.  For instance, both mawk and bwk (one-true-awk) give different results:

```
+ echo Ciência
+ gawk {print toupper($0);}
CIÊNCIA
+ echo Ciência
+ mawk {print toupper($0);}
CIêNCIA
+ echo Ciência
+ one-true-awk {print toupper($0);}
CIêNCIA
```

Comment: gawk or any POSIX-compliant awk (not mawk nor busybox awk though, the two other commonly found awk implementations on Linux-based systems). Why the intermediary `x` variable though?